# Best way to create / return xlsx file to Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I stuck on the problem of how to organize code / proper way to get xlsx file as output in flask app.
I have a function.py file where for now the xlsx file generates. 
The sense is that flask app gets some settings in json format, these settings are processed by function that must return xlsx(?) to app.

The function do some calculations depending on the settings.

The file has the next structure:

```
def function (settings):  
    settings=settings  
    df = pd.read_csv(settings['df'])  
    from pandas import ExcelWriter  
    writer = ExcelWriter('file.xlsx')  
    if settings[somefeature1]==1:  
        f1=dosmth.to_excel(writer, "feature 1")  
    if settings[somefeature2]==1:  
        f2=dosmth.to_excel(writer, "feature 2")  
    ...
    writer.save()
```

But if the file is already generated in function, what should I pass to flask? How the flask app function must look like then (especially in case if I want to return xlsx as json)?

```
@app.route('/Function', methods = ['POST'])  
def Function():  
    settings = request.get_json(force = True)  
    return(function(settings))    #???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never forget that flask is a framework for creating web applications, a web application is a piece of software that receives a **web request** and generates a **web response**.

To make it super simple: your flask function should return something that a common web browser will be able to handle. 
In this case your response should return the file but also some metadata to tell to the potential receiver what is inside the response and how to handle it.

I think that something like this could work:

```
return send_file(filename, mimetype='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```